# Draw a special LaTeX character with different fill and edge colours without resorting TikZ

Tags: symbols, color, amssymb

Is it possible to draw a special LaTeX character, e.g. `\blacklozenge` of `amssymb` package, with different fill and edge colours without resorting `TikZ`?

Inner region of `\blacklozenge` may be coloured as follows:

```
textcolor{red}{$\blacklozenge$}
```

However, this produces a red character surrounded by a red line. Is it possible to change the line colour to, say yellow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inset a shrunken red lozenge inside one of another color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,xcolor,stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\scalebox{.7}{\textcolor{red}{$\blacklozenge$}}}{%
  \textcolor{yellow!40!orange}{$\blacklozenge$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the inner lozenge a bit left of center?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. If one thinks so, one may change the 2nd argument of `\stackinset` from `{}` to a small length, such as `{.2pt}`, for example.  Such an offset might occur if the left/right sidebearing of the glyph were not symmetric.